# Execute a command in a different path

Tags: command-line, git, path

When using Git VCS, I execute all of the git commands on the directory that contains  a .git repository. I want to execute a git-pull through an SSH trigger but how do I define the path to the repository to perform the action on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you set the `GIT_DIR` environment variable, `git` will use it as a path to the repository.
2. In general, you can start a subshell like this:

   (cd /some/other/directory/; git pull)

The subshell will have its own current directory and environment variables.